# RegEx Assistance. Bash on OSX

Tags: regex, macos, bash

This is probably a simple question but I'm new to bash and OSX. I would like a regex expression that returns a string between two periods followed by the word LSSharedFileList.

For example "org.videolan.vlc.LSSharedFileList.plist.lockfile" would return only "vlc".

The beginning and end of the string may change but I will only ever need the text between the periods preceding "LSSharedFileList".

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Both answers worked brilliantly, so thank you both. I also managed a workaround using  "$string | cut -d'.' -f4`" to find the 4th from last 'column' defining '.' as the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo org.videolan.vlc.LSSharedFileList.plist.lockfile | sed -e 's/.*\.\(..*\)\.LSSharedFileList.*/\1/'
vlc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this using bash parameter expansion:

```
FOO="org.videolan.vlc.LSSharedFileList.plist.lockfile"

# Strip off ".LSSharedFileList" and whatever follows
BAR=${FOO%.LSSharedFileList*}

# Strip off everything from the beginning up to the first period
BAR=${BAR##*.}

echo $BAR
```